# Suppose that g is complex differentiable, and prove the following.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose that $g:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$ is complex differentiable and that $g(x+iy)=v(x,y)+i\tilde v(x,y)$.

Prove that $\langle\nabla v, \nabla\tilde v \rangle=0$.

Here's what I've attempted so far, but I'm not too sure if it is right, and so would like to ask if somebody could check it:

$\langle\nabla v, \nabla\tilde v \rangle= \nabla^2\langle v,\tilde v \rangle$

$=\nabla^2|v|^2 $

$=\frac \partial{\partial x ^2} ^2 (v^2)+\frac\partial{\partial y ^2} ^2 (v^2)$

$=\frac \partial{\partial x } (2v_xv)+\frac\partial{\partial y } (2v_yv) $

$=(2v_{xx}+2|v_x|^2)+(2v_{yy}+2|v_y|^2)$

$=2(v_{xx}+v_{yy})+2(|v_x|^2+|v_y|^2)$

$=0$, since $v_{xx}+v_{yy}=0$

Hence $\langle\nabla v, \nabla\tilde v \rangle=0$

Comment: It is not true that $\nabla^2 \langle v, \tilde{v} \rangle = \nabla^2 \langle v , \tilde{v} \rangle$ as the r.h.s. contains second order derivatives while the l.h.s. does not. Also $v$ and $\tilde{v}$ are real functions and it is not true in general that $\langle v, \tilde{v} \rangle = |v|^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Cauchy-Riemann equations $\partial_x v = \partial_y \tilde{v},~\partial_y v = -\partial_x \tilde{v}$
$$
\langle \nabla v, \nabla \tilde{v} \rangle = \partial_x v\partial_x \tilde{v} + \partial_y v\partial_y \tilde{v} =0
$$

Comment: I got it with the C-R equations. Thanks for your help!